# URI/URL Builder for JDBC URLs

Tags: postgresql, url, jdbc, uri

I'm trying to idiomatically add some new query parameters to a JDBC URL, yet the URI builders that are at my disposal don't work correctly with URLs like

`jdbc:postgres://localhost:6542/db`

It seems they don't correctly recognize the scheme (in this case jdbc:postgres) and wrongfully assume the scheme is `jdbc`.

Is there any idiomatic way to add query parameters to a JDBC URL?

Comment: Why don't you use properties instead of constructing and URL?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such mechanism, because those URL builders are generally intended for RFC 3986 compliant URLs (maybe even only designed for use with scheme `http` and `https`), and JDBC URLs are not compliant.

In fact, [JDBC 4.3](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html) only specifies the following:

> The format of a JDBC URL is :
>
> - jdbc:<subprotocol>:<subname>
>
> where `subprotocol` defines the kind of database connectivity
> mechanism that may be supported by one or more drivers. The contents
> and syntax of the `subname` will depend on the subprotocol.
>
> ---
>
> **Note** – A JDBC URL is not required to fully adhere to the URI syntax as defined in RFC 3986, Uniform Resource Identifier (URI):
> Generic Syntax.
>
> ---

As a result of this definition, essentially anything is valid for `subname`. Some drivers will seem to mimic RFC 3986, but may not require or support escapes. Some drivers support parameters (properties) in the URL, while others do not. Some may use `?` and `&` to separate properties, while others may use `;`, etc.

For PostgreSQL, you might get away with using a URL builder on `postgres://localhost:6542/db`, and adding the `jdbc:` prefix after building, but I'm not sure if PostgreSQL supports all features of a RFC 3986 URL, so you might still end up with an URL that cannot be properly parsed by the driver.

As suggested in the comments by [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe), consider using a `Properties` object (when using `DriverManager` directly), or use mechanisms of your data source to set properties, instead of relying on passing those properties through the URL.

For example, when using `DriverManager`, you'd use:

```java
String url = "jdbc:postgres://localhost:6542/db";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", username);
props.setProperty("password", password);
props.setProperty("property1", "value1");
// ...
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props)) {
    // use connection
}
```